# How to draw a gradient line/circle in IOS with Core Graphics

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, core-graphics

I know how to draw a circle
 // Drawing code

```
CGContextClearRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0f);

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0.5 blue:0 alpha:0.5].CGColor);
CGRect circlePoint = CGRectMake(startX, startY, circleDiameter, circleDiameter);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, circlePoint);//
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
CGContextStrokeEllipseInRect(context, circlePoint);
```

But how could I draw a line/circle with a gradient, i.g. fading in from black to white (and maybe fading out from white to black on the other side as well) ?

Comment: Create a circle path, use that as your clipping path (`CGContextClip()`), then draw your gradient. I'm sure someone can give a coded example...

Comment: If you have additional drawing to do in your context, you should save your graphics context state (`CGContextSaveGState()`) before you set your clipping path and restore it later (`CGContexrRestoreGState()`)